# Is there a standard for call.end() and call.on('end')?

Tags: node.js, grpc

I'm working with a bi-directional gRPC stream.

I set the call up, make several calls to call.write() and finally make a call to call.end()

In between the calls to call.write I have a call.on('data') event handler.

My question is... when I'm done with the stream and I call call.end() should I expect the server to emit an 'end' event?

Is there a standard for this?

I've seen some examples where the server does emit an end event and some that don't.

I'm just trying to figure out what best practice is.

Answer (score 0):

In the Node gRPC server, the `end` event signals that all messages have been received, the same as on the client. The server will always emit that event, unless there is an error in the stream (which will be indicated by the `cancelled` event if it did not come from the server application).

Other languages have their own conventions for representing streams, so gRPC servers in those languages will not specifically have an `end` event to listen for, but they will have some way of indicating that a stream has ended. You should check the documentation for the language you are working in to determine what that is.

Answer (score -1):

In gRPC, the `end()` method on the client-side and the `end()` method on the server-side are used to signal the end of the bidirectional stream. However, whether the server emits an 'end' event after receiving the `end()` call from the client is not standardized in the gRPC specification.

The server-side can choose to emit an 'end' event or not based on its implementation. Some servers may emit an 'end' event when they receive an `end()` call from the client, while others may not emit an 'end' event.

Therefore, whether you should expect the server to emit an 'end' event after calling `call.end()` depends on the implementation of the server you are working with. In general, it is a good practice to listen to the 'end' event on both the client-side and server-side streams to detect the end of the stream.

To summarize, there is no standardized behavior for the `end()` method and the 'end' event in gRPC, and it may vary depending on the implementation of the server.